# how can I re-write the code by using try, throw, catch and finally to handle the errors?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, throw, finally

This is actually a fully functional code (if anybody wants to use). My question is how to re-write the code by using try..catch..throw..finally syntax to handle the errors

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".submit").click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault()

        var email = $(".email").val()
        var subject = $(".subject").val()
        var statusElm = $(".status")
        statusElm.empty()

        if(email.length > 5 && email.includes("@") && email.includes(".")) {
    statusElm.append("<div>valid email</div>")
        }else{
    statusElm.append("<div>invalid email</div>")
        }

        if(subject.length > 2) {
    statusElm.append("<div>Valid Subject</div>")
        }else{
    statusElm.append("<div>invalid subject</div>")
        }
    })
})
```

UPDATE:
I came up with something like this;

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit").click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault()

        var email = $(".email").val()
        var subject = $(".subject").val()
        var statusElm = $(".status")
        statusElm.empty()


  try { 
    if(email.length > 5 && email.includes("@") && email.includes("."))  throw "is not an email";
    if(subject.length > 2) throw "is not long enough";

  }
  catch(err) {
    status.innerHTML = "Input " + err;
   }
    })
  })
```

but its not executing. I dont know how to make it work.

Comment: I like your original code better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `try/catch/throw/finally` *practically* when the code actually throws an error. You could throw your own error inside the `try`, but that would be defeating the purpose.

Comment: I want to use user input for that.

Answer (score 0):

I created another function for the try, and catch parts in a different JS file, so all good. Just wanted to let everyone know.